# Setting a parameter inside a string of an array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function `language($tag)` that requires a file `lang.php` which contains an array called `$lang` which contains some parameters. In particular a string `$lang['message']`. After some execution lines it returns `$lang['message']`.

The $lang array is defined as follows:

```
$lang[$tag] = array(
    'message' => 'This is a message',
    ...
);
```

Now let's say I'd like to be able to set parameters inside `$lang['message']` that I should be able to define on `language($tag, $parameters)`. And these parameters should set a var inside `$lang['message']` such as:

```
$lang[$tag] = array(
    'message' => 'This is a '. $1,
    ...
);
```

How is the best way of organize `language($tag, $parameters)` so that what is in `$parameters` sets `$1` in `$lang['message']`?

If you didn't understand I'd like to be able to call `language($tag, 'post')` and make it return `'This is a post'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about saving the strings as `printf` templates, eg

```
$lang[$tag] = array(
    'message' => 'This is a %s'
);
```

You can then use [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) to pass an array of value substitutions, eg

```
function language($tag, array $values)
{
    // get $lang from somewhere

    return vsprintf($lang[$tag]['message'], $values);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be using `sprintf()`.

```
'message' => 'This is a %s',
```

And you just use it like this:

```
sprintf($lang['message'], 'post');
```

Please read the [manual page of `sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to see its numerous capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) for my language function.

The solution would probably look like this:

```
$lang = array(
    'stop' => 'Stop right there!',
    'message' => 'This is a %s',
    'double_message' => 'This is a %s with %s comments',
    ...
);
```

And:

```
function language()
{
    $lang = get_lang_from_file(); // You probably have the idea
    $params = func_get_args();


    if(count($params) == 1)
        return $lang[$params[0]];

    $params[0] = $lang[$params[0]];
    return call_user_func_array("sprintf", $params);
}
```

This way you can use it like this:

```
echo language('stop'); // outputs 'Stop right there!'
echo language('message', 'message for you'); // outputs 'This is a message for you'
echo language('double_message', 'message for you', '6'); // outputs 'This is a message for you with 6 comments
```

Comment: `vsprintf()` is a lot nicer than `sprintf` via `call_user_func_array()`